# Defer on a struct sqlx.Close() ends in a stack overflow

Tags: go

I just started learning Go. Lesson of the day was to wrap my database handler in a struct to avoid using global scope variables. Thought I understood it so far and wanted to defer the Close() method as I did before, which ended in an stack overflow.

I couldn't find an explanation why this happen, nor what's the propper way to do this.

Here is the key code:

```
package exporter

type DB struct {
    *sqlx.DB
    queriesExecuted int
}

func Open(dataSourceName string) *DB {
    connection := sqlx.MustConnect("mysql", dataSourceName)
    db := &DB{connection, 0}
    return db
}

func (db *DB) Close() {
    db.Close() // this is where the stack growth happens
}

func (db *DB) GetArticles() []oxarticle {
  ... 
}
```

---

```
package main

func main() {
    exporter := feedexporter.Open("root:pass@/feedexport")
    defer exporter.Close()

    articles := exporter.GetArticles()
}
```

Everything works fine without the defer exporter.Close(), including it ends in:

> runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit
>
> fatal error: stack overflow

It feels so bad to not close connections ;) What's the propper way to handle this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're triggering an infinite recursion in your `Close()` method:

```
func (db *DB) Close() {
    db.Close() // you're currently IN this exact method!
}
```

What you're probably meaning to do is calling the `Close()` method of the `sqlx.DB` struct that's embedded in your custom `DB` struct. I'm not that familiar with the `sqlx` package, but [according to the documentation](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#connecting) that type does not even have a `Close()` method. This is most probably because the `sqlx.DB` does not actually represent a single connection, but a connection pool that creates and closes connections transparently:

> A DB instance is not a connection, but an abstraction representing a Database. This is why creating a DB does not return an error and will not panic. It maintains a connection pool internally, and will attempt to connect when a connection is first needed.

The [documentation](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#connectionPool) explains in-depth how to handle this connection pool (emphasis mine):

> By default, the pool grows unbounded, and connections will be created whenever there isn't a free connection available in the pool. You can use DB.SetMaxOpenConns to set the maximum size of the pool. **Connections that are not being used are marked idle and then closed if they aren't required**. To avoid making and closing lots of connections, set the maximum idle size with DB.SetMaxIdleConns to a size that is sensible for your query loads.
>
> It is easy to get into trouble by accidentally holding on to connections. To prevent this:
>
> 1. Ensure you Scan() every Row object
> 2. **Ensure you either Close() or fully-iterate via Next() every Rows object**
> 3. Ensure every transaction returns its connection via Commit() or Rollback()